# "Бизнес-идея" — через дефис?

Tags: орфография

Словосочетание **"бизнес-идея"** пишется через дефис?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, здесь **дефисное написание,** другой вариант просто невозможен (два нарицательных существительных без соединительной гласной).

Бизнес ― это **приложение** (определение) по своей семантике, но так как оно не склоняется, то образует **сложное слово** "бизнес-идея".

Вообще говоря, раньше допускалось раздельное написание сочетаний вида "старик (старый) сторож, красавица (красивая) невеста", но сейчас и они пишутся через дефис.